# crash on pthread_cond_timedwait and pthread_mutex_lock

Tags: multithreading, mutex

This is thread A code.

```
void sleep(Data x)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &(X->lock) );
    struct timeval  _T;
    gettimeofday( &_T, 0 );
    T.tv_sec = _T.tv_sec;
    T.tv_nsec = 1000 * _T.tv_usec;
    pthread_cond_timedwait( &(x->condition), &(x->lock), &T );
    x->value = 0;
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &(x->lock) );
}
```

Below is thread B code

```
void wakeup(Data y)
{

    pthread_mutex_lock( &(y->lock) );
    y->value = 1;
    pthread_cond_signal( &(y->condition) );
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &(y->lock) );
}
struct Data {
    pthread_cond_t  condition;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    int             value;
} ;
```

I am facing a crash in a multithreaded system. Where as per bt one thread (A) is showing in `pthread_cond_timedwait` and other thread (B) is in `pthread_mutex_lock`. Thread B got some data to wake up thread A.
Crash is happening at the same time as passed as timeout `pthread_cond_timedwait`. Crash is showing in thread B. As per bt value is "0".

In the code section please don't look for syntax mistakes. All the variables are initilized properly

Comment: re: please don’t look for syntax mistakes...   What are you asking?   Do these primitives work?  Yes, you haven’t discovered a massive set of bugs, you have done something wrong.   If you want people to look at it, try and have the courtesy to provide an example that demonstrates your problem, not a vague outline that can’t compile.

Comment: improved formatting